# Clear R Console programmatically

Tags: windows, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function to Clear the Console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r)

Is there a way to invoke the Clear Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) menu command programmatically?

Comment: The Mac OSX R.app equivalent is <Cmd><Opt><L>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use a function for doing that, and actually have put it in {R directory}\etc\Rprofile.site so that it will always be available for use.

```
cls <- function() {
        require(rcom)
        wsh <- comCreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        comInvoke(wsh, "SendKeys", "\014")
        invisible(wsh)
 }
cls()
```

To clear the console give

```
cls()
```

P.S. The function doesn't work the first time it's called and that's why I invoke the function immediately after declaring it in Rprofile.site. As I recall, you may be asked to install some program, in order for this to work.

Comment: As RCom has been discontinued, I thought it might be worth porting this to PowerShell (available on most Windows systems these days) `cls <- function() {
 system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string][char]12)");
}`

Answer (score 1):

Create this function:

```
cls <- function() cat(rep("\n",100))
```

Then call it:

```
cls()
```

Works with:

- Windows
- Linux
- Mac

Comment: This doesn't actually clear the console. Just prints 100 new lines.

Comment: @Siddharth. You're right. When I use this cls(), the intent is to get rid of the previous commands, this pushes them away off the top of the screen.

Comment: I like this because it achieves the intended effect

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point dramatically, but is simple `system("clear")` an easier approach? Of course, it can only be applied on Linux/Unix environments...