# Function to clear the console in R and RStudio

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a function to clear the console in R and, in particular, RStudio I am looking for a function that I can type into the console, and not a keyboard shortcut.

Someone has already provided such a function in [this StackExchange post from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824965/clear-r-console-programmatically). Unfortunately, this depends on the RCom package and will not run on Mac OS X.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but it's pretty highly related and the answer to this question was given in the following - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421005/r-about-removing-all-of-the-typed-commands-from-the-command-window/8422206#8422206

Comment: Only type `clc` with this script [clc.R](https://github.com/HubertRonald/clcR) that I development. How does it work? `clc<-0`; `class(clc) <- 'cleanup'`; `print.cleanup <- function(cleanupObject) cat("\f")`. The last line corresponds to RStudio but in terminal change it by `print.cleanup <- function(cleanupObject) cat(c("\033[2J","\033[H"))`. The [clc.R](https://github.com/HubertRonald/clcR) contains more details.

Comment: I found this command system("clear") similar to clear in bash which clean up everything even scrolling up.

Answer (score 616, accepted):

```
cat("\014")
```

is the code to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to the console, and therefore will clear the screen.

Far better than just sending a whole lot of returns.

Comment: This just prints a single blank line to my interactive terminal (on both Ubuntu and Mac OSX)

Comment: Works for me. This might also help with the *extremely slow console*-bug in Rstudio.

Comment: Works for me in RStudio on Windows Xp

Comment: Works in RStudio on Mac, but not in R.app! In R.app the command Cmd+Alt+L clears the screen, not Ctrl+L... Is there a similar 'code' to send that key combination to the R.app? (I see that \014 is the ASCII code for Form Feed, so I guess it is not sending the key combination but just the Form Feed command, which makes it unlikely that a 'code' for Cmd+Alt+L would exist.)

Comment: does not work for me. windows 7, R console. (r.exe).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me. Windows 8.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on OSX.  See my posted answer for one that does work on osx and linux.

Comment: This works only in RStudio on Windows, not in the "usual" R console nor in a DOS console. For the record, it's also the Form Feed character, and you can just type `cat("\f")`.

Comment: How can you clear the top margin too? - - You can still browse the history with your mouse, for instance. Can you clear it too? - - OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Works on gnome terminal on debian 8.

Comment: @E Luxo So, where can I find a list of these codes? In particular, I’m looking for a way to send backspace using an r snippet

Answer (score 107):

If you are using the default R console, the key combination <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will clear the console.

Comment: CTRL-L just in case you thought that was an "i", like me :)

Comment: Ctrl + L for Rstudio on OSX Yosemite as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP wanted a function and clearly said not a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 37):

You may define the following function

```
clc <- function() cat(rep("\n", 50))
```

which you can then call as `clc()`.

Comment: This does not clear the console rather it inserts 50 empty lines which push the output up.

Answer (score 36):

`shell("cls")` if on Windows,

`shell("clear")` if on Linux or Mac.

(`shell()` passes a command (or any string) to the host terminal.)

Comment: This worked. It is not as elegant as the other answers, but far easier to remember.

Comment: This is the only command that worked for me in the Rterm console on Windows 10... but what a pain to have to type all that...

Comment: Yep, that's why I learned it - I also use the R terminal on Windows 10 (much easier than loading up RStudio) - and it's handy to be able to pass commands to the shell.
I believe there is a way in R to sort of "map" a sequence of characters to a particular command, although I can't remember exactly how to do it - I think it's a bit like an alias in bash, or maybe it's more like a function - but you could do that to reduce the amount of typing.
(For instance, I think you could set it up where something like `clr()` or `clr` runs the command `shell("cls")` or `shell("clear")`.)

Comment: Likewise, this was the only one that worked for both RStudio, and my Windows 7 shell (cmd.exe) windows.  To .Rprofile I've added:  `clear_fun <- function() shell("cls"); makeActiveBinding("cls", clear_fun, baseenv());`

Comment: This works for the terminal in Visual Studio Code on Windows.

Comment: `shell("cls")` is the only one that works for me if i use it in code in a [snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets?version=1.2.5033&mode=desktop)

Answer (score 31):

`cat("\f")` may be easier to remember than `cat("\014")`.

It works fine for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 27):

In *Ubuntu-Gnome*, simply pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> should clear the screen.

This also seems to also work well in Windows 10 and 7 and Mac OS X Sierra.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a function:

```
clear <- function() cat(c("\033[2J","\033[0;0H"))
```

then you can simply call it, as you call any other R function, `clear()`.

If you prefer to simply type `clear` (instead of having to type `clear()`, i.e. with the parentheses), then you can do

```
clear_fun <- function() cat(c("\033[2J","\033[0;0H"));
makeActiveBinding("clear", clear_fun, baseenv())
```

Comment: Much like the `\014` approach, this approach gives me funny characters (from the R console on a Windows 10 machine).

Comment: Unlike \014 (or \f) this worked for me on Windows 10 in Rterm.

Comment: @MartiniBianco: I think that the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348563/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-linux-c-c) should help.  Basically "\033" is "ESC".  The "[2J" and "[0;0H" clear the screen and move the cursor to upper left, respectively.

Answer (score 16):

I developed an R package that will do this, borrowing from the suggestions above.  The package is called called `mise`, as in "mise en place."  You can install and run it using

```
install.packages("mise")
library(mise)
mise()
```

Note that `mise()` also deletes all variables and functions and closes all figures by default.  To just clear the console, use `mise(vars = FALSE, figs = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 10):

In linux use `system("clear")` to clear the screen.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the default R console <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

RStudio - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Works on macOS too

Comment: The question asks for a function and specifically says does not want a keyboard shortcut!

Answer (score 5):

cat("\014") . This will work. no worries

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the following two commands

```
cat("\014"); 
cat(rep("\n", 50))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for RStudio is `rstudioapi::sendToConsole("\014")`. This will work even if output is diverted.

```
sink("out.txt")

cat("\014") # Console not cleared

rstudioapi::sendToConsole("\014") # Console cleared

sink()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I found myself visiting it many times looking for a totally different answer:

```
n = 20
for (i in 0:n) {
  cat(100*i/n, "% \r")
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(0.01) #do something slow
}
```

`flush.console()` will kind of "clear the console in r and studio", maybe not in OP's terms but still.

This code will act like a progress bar in the console. For each iteration, the percentage is incremented and then erased on the next iteration.

Note that this won't work without `\r` or with an `\n`, for some reason.