# Can you unprint a line in R?

Tags: r, printing, console

I am writing up some data processing stuff and I wanted to have a concise progress status printing a fraction that updates over time on a single line in the console.

To get this done I wanted to have something like this

```
print(Initiating data processing...)
for(sample in 1:length(data)){
   print(paste(sample,length(data),sep="/"))
   process(data[[sample]])
   #Unprint the bottom line in the console ... !!! ... !!!.. ?
}
```

Keeping the screen clean and what not. I don't quite know how to do it. I know that there is a [R text progress bar](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html) but for utilities sake I'm looking for a little more control.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Why not print 'Data processing complete'. Users will be familiar with that format of console communication.

Comment: Are you asking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14260340/1270695

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your best bet is to do exactly what the R text progress bar does, which is "`\r` to return to the left margin", as seen in the help file. You'll have to use `cat` instead of `print` because `print` ends with a newline.

```
cat("Initiating data processing...\n")
for(sample in 1:length(data)){
   cat(sample, length(data), sep="/")
   process(data[[sample]])
   cat("\r")
}
cat("\n")
```