# Clear terminal in R-3.2.1 on CentOS 6, put cursor on top

Tags: r

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r) having already been asked, however neither `cat("\014")`  nor `Option + Command + L` works for me.  `cls <- function() cat(rep("\n",50))` works, however the cursor remains at the bottom of the screen.

I am using OS X Mavericks for my local machine and I am running R remotely (via ssh). I am using Terminal.app on my local machine to do so.

Note : `Control + Command + L` works if I, if on the server side, I launch an X11 window (via `xterm`) and run R from there.  However, I don't particularly like working in an X11 window.

Note : in my `.inputrc` I have `set editing-mode vi`. I'm not sure if that will effect clearing the screen. It does not seem to be an issue in the X11 window.

QUESTION : How would I clear the screen while remotely running the command line version of R from Terminal.app and have the cursor be at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r/38106949#38106949) :

`clear <- function() cat(c("\033[2J","\033[0;0H"))`