# Is there a command character to pass "CTRL+8" to the console?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am setting up my .Rprofile and I would like Rstudio to open the environment tab on open.

I am looking for something like the cat("\014") command that clears the console.

[Function to clear the console in R and RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r-and-rstudio)