# Clearing Console/Terminal in R in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: r, windows, cmd, terminal, console

For some reason I am unable to use RStudio in my PC and decided to use R from command prompt.

However I am unable to do the CTRL+L thing in CMD.

How to clear console in CMD? I tried `clc`, `clear`, `cls`, etc.

Comment: https://appuals.com/how-to-clear-console-in-r-and-rstudio/

Comment: Or [Function to clear the console in R and RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r-and-rstudio), see @HubertRonald's comment and [this their script](https://github.com/HubertRonald/clcR/blob/master/clc.R)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac it's `<option>+<cmd>+L`. Works in both R.app and R started in a Terminal window. Might be OS specific.